# The most efficient method to render html in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have to implement some html render in C# and we are searching for efficient method to do it.

Here is the html we want to render:

```
<h1> Title {34}</h1>
<p>Paragraph  {4}</p>
<div> Div here {14}</div>
```

The numbers {34}, {4}, {14} must be replaced with values from dictionary.

We are looking for efficient find, extract number and replace. The html dynamic and numbers too.

One solution is to use regex but do we have a better alternative?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? What are your performance requirement?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5+, no specific requirements. The idea is to find and replace a lot of numbers inside the html.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ `don’t make performance-based changes unless you’ve identified a performance problem.` In other words, start with Razor since it will almost certainly be good enough.

Comment: @Tori When exactly do you want to replace the numbers? The way you're phrasing it, it sounds like the page is going to render with the numbers and you want to replace them after the fact (which means javascript). If that's not what you mean, why not just insert them with razor?

Comment: if your html looks like this always 
you may use xml reader
you can then replace by linq or using loops

Comment: @UsmanAsif What is the benefit of doing that over Razor? Is it faster?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis we want to read html from file, replace numbers with translations from dictionary<no, value> and serve the html over .ashx
The problem is working with strings, how we can handle such problems and not related with framework or technology rather than programming methodology. It can be in Java, Javascript, C#, Python or any other language.

Comment: @Tori Where is the dictionary stored? Do the numbers you want to replace always appear in the format `{x}` where `x` is the number? Is the number `x` always the key of the dictionary entry? `dict[x] = value`, so you want `{x}` to be replaced with `value`. Correct?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis the proposed format is {x} where x represent key of dictionary, list or array and with all known values. Your answer is one solution with regex Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what benchmarking with Razor you have already performed, and what target you are aiming for? Note that 'as fast as possible' is not an acceptable response.

Comment: @mjwills I don't know Razor technology, If you know you can post an answer with your results. And second, what's the problem about searching for fastest method in my case?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is you have a static html file taken from somewhere else and you want to replace the pattern `{x}` with `dict[x]`, where x is a number and a key to a dictionary value. This can be done with regex, either server-side with C# (or anything else really) or client-side with Javascript. Here's a sample js solution:

```js
const oldHTML = "<h1>Title {34}</h1><p>Paragraph {4}</p><div> Div here {14}</div>"
document.querySelector('#before').innerHTML = oldHTML;


const dict = {
    "4": "dict value for 4",
    "14": "dict value for 14",
    "34": "dict value for 34"
};

const newHTML = oldHTML.replace(/\{[0-9]+\}/g, (str) => {
  const num = str.slice(1, str.length - 1);
  return dict[num];
});
document.querySelector('#after').innerHTML = newHTML;
```

```html
<div id="before"></div>
<div id="after"></div>
```

I don't know what exactly you mean by "efficient", but this should do the trick. If you don't want it done client-side, use a similar solution on your server. It really depends on where this "dictionary" is stored and how you intend to get values from it.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that one solution is to use regex. The problem with regex is that we have to find all matches and replaced one by one. Performing replacement one by one looks to be not effective.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a solution which not only is faster than split but also is memory efficient and suitable for stream manipulation.

Here is the c# code (I put your solution together with my solution so we could compare running time):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace htmlRender
{
    class Program
    {
        const string oldHTML = "<h1>Title {34}</h1><p>Paragraph {4}</p><div> Div here {14}</div>";
        static Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {  "4", "dict value for 4" },
                { "14", "dict value for 14"},
                { "34", "dict value for 34"}
            };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"{\d+}");

            string newHTMLRegex = rx.Replace(oldHTML, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceText));
            sw.Stop();
            //Console.WriteLine(newHTMLRegex);
            Console.WriteLine("Execution time regex took " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks.");

            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var str = oldHTML.Split(new char[] { '{', '}' });
            if (str.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    sb.Append(str[i]);
                    if (str.Length > i + 1)
                        sb.Append(dict[str[i + 1]]);
                }
            }
            string newHTMLSplit = sb.ToString();
            sw.Stop();
            //Console.WriteLine(newHTMLSplit);
            Console.WriteLine("Execution time split took " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks.");


            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var charBuffer = new char[10];
            int buffered = 0;
            bool buffering = false;
            var writer = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < oldHTML.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!buffering && oldHTML[i] == '{')
                {
                    buffering = true;
                }
                else if (buffering)
                {
                    if (oldHTML[i] == '}')
                    {
                        writer.Append(dict[new string(charBuffer, 0, buffered)]);
                        buffered = 0;
                        buffering = false;
                    }
                    else if (oldHTML[i] == '0' ||
                            oldHTML[i] == '1' ||
                            oldHTML[i] == '2' ||
                            oldHTML[i] == '3' ||
                            oldHTML[i] == '4' ||
                            oldHTML[i] == '5' ||
                            oldHTML[i] == '6' ||
                            oldHTML[i] == '7' ||
                            oldHTML[i] == '8' ||
                            oldHTML[i] == '9')
                    {
                        charBuffer[buffered] = oldHTML[i];
                        buffered += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.Append(new string(charBuffer, 0, buffered));
                        buffered = 0;
                        buffering = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.Append(oldHTML[i]);
                }
            }

            string newHTMLStream = writer.ToString();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(newHTMLStream);
            Console.WriteLine("Execution time stream took " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks.");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string ReplaceText(Match m)
        {
            string x = m.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");

            return dict[x];
        }
    }
}
```

Execution times for one of my runs were:

```
Execution time regex took 17814 ticks.
Execution time split took 100 ticks.
Execution time stream took 51 ticks.
```

Best regards,
Betim Beja.

Comment: Impressive, the lower to machine code you go the better performance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found something I would like to share. Note that rendering html is of special format that contains `{num}`

Here is the code in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace htmlRender
{
    class Program
    {
        const string oldHTML = "<h1>Title {34}</h1><p>Paragraph {4}</p><div> Div here {14}</div>";
        static Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {  "4", "dict value for 4" },
                { "14", "dict value for 14"},
                { "34", "dict value for 34"}
            };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"{\d+}");

            string newHTMLRegex = rx.Replace(oldHTML, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceText));
            sw.Stop();
            //Console.WriteLine(newHTMLRegex);
            Console.WriteLine("Execution time regex took " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks.");


            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var str = oldHTML.Split(new char[] { '{', '}' });
            if (str.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    sb.Append(str[i]);
                    if (str.Length > i + 1)
                        sb.Append(dict[str[i + 1]]);
                }
            }
            string newHTMLSplit = sb.ToString();
            sw.Stop();
            //Console.WriteLine(newHTMLSplit);
            Console.WriteLine("Execution time split took " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks.");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string ReplaceText(Match m)
        {
            string x = m.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");

            return dict[x];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my execution in ticks with significant improvement

```
Execution time regex took 6894 ticks.
Execution time split took 65 ticks.
```

Also here is the JavaScript version following [@irakslis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12398336/iraklis-gkougkousis) answer:

```js
const oldHTML = "<h1>Title {34}</h1><p>Paragraph {4}</p><div> Div here {14}</div>";
        document.querySelector('#oldHTML').innerHTML = oldHTML;

        const dict = {
            "4": "dict value for 4",
            "14": "dict value for 14",
            "34": "dict value for 34"
        };
        let start = performance.now();

        let newHTML = oldHTML.replace(/\{[0-9]+\}/g, (str) => {
            const num = str.slice(1, str.length - 1);
            return dict[num];
        });

        var end = performance.now();
        console.log("Execution time regex took " + (end - start) + " milliseconds.");
        document.querySelector('#newHtmlRegex').innerHTML = newHTML;

        start = performance.now();
        let sb = [];
        var str = oldHTML.split(/{|}/);

        if (str.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
                sb.push(str[i]);
                if (str.length > i + 1)
                    sb.push(dict[str[i + 1]]);
            }
        }
        newHTML = sb.join('');

        end = performance.now();
        console.log("Execution time split took " + (end - start) + " milliseconds.");
        document.querySelector('#newHtmlSplit').innerHTML = newHTML;
```

```html
   <div id="oldHTML"></div>
   <div id="newHtmlRegex"></div>
   <div id="newHtmlSplit"></div>
```

The html implementation performance is 30-70% faster with split instead of regex.

```
Execution time regex took 0.1550000160932541 milliseconds.
Execution time split took 0.044999876990914345 milliseconds.
```